# adding png to existing PDF using itextsharp

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, itext

I'm writing a application in **C# winforms**. I'm currently trying to add an **image to an existing pdf** using the itextsharp library. I'm loading the pdf using a WebBrowser control and I want to allow the user to **add an image to the bottom of the PDF** using  an OpenFileDialog.

My first thought was to pull the file path by using:

```
webBrowser1.Url.ToString();
```

However, When i insert that line into the FileStream I get the following error. **URI formats are not supported.**

```
 using (Stream inputFile = new FileStream(webBrowser1.Url.ToString(),FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
```

How can I pull the path and filename from the WebBrowser control into the filestream?

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- you can use new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadData method to download that file,
  or
- iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance method supports URLs as well.